# Non-local commutator $[\phi(x), \phi(y)] = i\pi \textrm{sgn}(x-y)$ of 1D chiral boson: why?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, bosonization

It is well-known from [bosonization](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275) that 1D chiral boson has the commutation relation
$$[\phi(x), \phi(y)] = i\pi \mathrm{sgn}(x-y). \tag{1}$$

This gives the correct anticommutation relation for the fermion operator $\psi^\dagger \sim e^{i\phi}$. However, it is not intuitive that the commutation relation is non-local.

Recall when we first learn QFT. There, a free boson field
$$\Phi(x) = \sum_k e^{ikx} a_k,$$
where $[a_k, a_k^\dagger]=1$, satisfies the commutation relation
$$[\Phi(x), \Phi^\dagger(y)] = 2\pi\delta(x-y).\tag{2}$$
Here, $\Phi$ is not Hermitian and the commutation relation with its conjugate is local.

Equation (1) is very different with (2). How should I understand the non-local commutation relation (1)? Is this related to the peculiarities of 1D?

Note: 1. The non-local commutation can be seen the mode expansion
$$\phi(x) = -\sum_{q>0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_q}} (e^{-iqx} b_q + e^{iqx} b_q^\dagger)\tag{3}$$
of the 1D boson field (see [review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275)), where $[b_q, b_q^\dagger]=1$. The strange factor $1/\sqrt{n_q}$, not present in (2), is the origin for $(1)$. Why we have the strange factor?

2. Taking derivative on ($1$), we have $$[\phi(x), \partial \phi(y)] = -2i \pi \delta(x-y)\tag{4},$$ which is local. Interestingly, $\phi$ is local with the density operator $\partial\phi$.

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): What definition of a chiral boson do you use?

Comment: @Qmechanic I cannot understand your question fully but the one I use has the mode expansion (3).

Answer (score 2):

1. If OP is mainly worried about the non-locality of the commutation relation (1), it should be pointed out that there exists an equivalent formulation of a self-dual/chiral boson $\chi=\partial\phi$ that has local commutation relation
   $$ [\chi(x),\chi(y)]~=~  -2i \pi \delta^{\prime}(x-y), $$
   cf. Ref. 1.
2. Of course this is merely a reformulation, and as usual there is no free lunch: the action functional for $\chi$ is [non-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlocal_Lagrangian) while the action functional for $\phi$ is local, cf. Ref. 1.

References:

1. R. Floreanini & R. Jackiw, *Self-dual fields as charge-density solitons,* [Phys. Rev. Lett. 59 (1987) 1873](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.59.1873).